# layout.template_modifiers() doesn't work

Tags: scripting, modifiers, interface

Code works, but layout `(layout.template_modifiers())` with the list of the modifiers are not disabled

```
import bpy

class LayoutModifier(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Layout Modifier"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"


    def draw(self, _context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.template_modifiers()


from bpy.utils import register_class

if __name__ == "__main__":

    register_class(LayoutModifier)
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the relevant code?  What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: The code works. It can be run in Blender. A header will appear in the "object" section, but there will be nothing inside this header, although in theory there should be a list with modifiers

Comment: I think template_modifiers is broken.  There's at least one bug against it: [T88655](https://developer.blender.org/T88655) that I've just confirmed is in 2.96 and 3.0

Comment: I also just confirmed that your class looks just like the code that is used to generate the modifiers panel, except for the add modifiers menu.  Oddly when I add the add modifiers menu to your draw routine, I can use it in Object Data to add a modifier but the modifier only shows up in the modifiers tab and not your new panel.